# InvalidImage Microsoft Graph API 400 error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

When making a put or patch request as specified in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), in order to update a team image, I get a 400 error. I am passing a valid binary as my request body in a JSON format:

```
{
 "photo": "binary data here"
}
```

And have also tried with base-64 encoding. Interestingly, if I use the `/groups` endpoint (instead of the `/teams` endpoint) **and** I leave out the `/$value` param, I get an error that at least tells me something:

```
"code": "InvalidImage"
"message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileBadRequestException' was thrown.",
```

However I'm not sure what to make of this as it is a valid image. For what it's worth, I'm using delegated permissions and have the correct scope (`TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All`)

Comment: How are you converting Image to Binary data?

Comment: @Rukmini first I get the base64 representation (base64.b64encode(requests.get(image_url).content)) and then `"".join(format(ord(x), "b") for x in base64.decodestring(output))`